# Date not coming correctly after formate in swift

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I have separated date and time according to my code, then I have used `DateFormatter` but date not coming correctly.. why?

coming like this: **Optional("08/15/0020")**

```
  var formateFromdate: String?
  var formateTodate: String?

  func addDate(){

  var fromDateArr = fromDateLabel.text!.components(separatedBy: ",")
        fromDate = fromDateArr[0]
        fromTime = fromDateArr[1].replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
  var toDateArr   = toDateLabel.text!.components(separatedBy: ",")
        toDate = toDateArr[0]
        toTime  = toDateArr[1].replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        
        let inputFormatter = DateFormatter()
        inputFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
                 
        let showDateFrom = inputFormatter.date(from: fromDate)
        inputFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
        formateFromdate = inputFormatter.string(from: showDateFrom!)
        print(formateFromdate)
        }
```

note: **here `fromDate = 08/15/2020` coming correct but after formate date not coming correct**

**OutPut:**

```
    Optional("08/15/0020") it should be 08/15/2020
```

Comment: Is the value of `fromDate` "08/15/20" or "08/15/2020"?

Comment: @Jithin fromDate = "08/15/2020"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the formatted date output, it seems the value of `fromDate = fromDateArr[0]` is `"08/15/20"` If that's the case, you will have to use a date format as below;

```
    let inputFormatter = DateFormatter()
    inputFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy"
    
    let showDateFrom = inputFormatter.date(from: fromDate)
    inputFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    let formateFromdate = inputFormatter.string(from: showDateFrom!)
    print(formateFromdate)
```

Comment: no its coming correct fromDate  = 08/15/2020 but only formateFromdate = 08/15/0020

Comment: Can you print `fromDateLabel.text` and add it in question?

Comment: date coming correctly in json `Message = "Text '08/16/2020 11:58:00AM' could not be parsed: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 16"`.      why? any idea

Comment: are you using `dd/MM/yyyy`? That's what the error says

Comment: actually before date not coming properly, if i give like your code then its coming like above error in console... now what should i do... now i am using `MM/dd/yy`

Comment: fromDateLabel.text value Optional("8/16/20, 11:58 AM")
fromdate after formate Optional("08/16/2020")

Comment: nooo coming like tis in console `Message = "Text '08/16/2020 11:58:00AM' could not be parsed: Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 16"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219852/discussion-between-jithin-and-iosapp).

Comment: hey once come to chat room, one doubt

Comment: thank you soo much.. chat room code worked perfectly :) my mistake i didn't notice the change

Answer (score 1):

You need to unwrap it first

```
if let formate = inputFormatter.string(from: showDateFrom!){
        print(formate)
}
```

Comment: if i give like this `if let formate: string{}` also out put `08/1/0020`

Comment: here `fromDate` coming correct but after formate going like this

Comment: I did not understand the problem now ... can you elaborate?